# QtConcurrent::map crashes if no QProgressDialog is shown

Tags: c++, qt5, qtconcurrent

Consider this `SLOT`, in my main thread, trigged by a button, which takes a list of `QTreeWidgetItem` from a `QTreeWidget`. It uses a `QtConcurrent::map()` call to execute a long task. The `watcher` connects to a `QProgressDialog` to show progress.

```
void Main::on_actionButton_triggered() {
    qRegisterMetaType<QVector<int> >("QVector<int>");

    //Setting up a progress dialog
    QProgressDialog progressDialog;

    //Holds the list
    QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> list;

    //Setup watcher
    QFutureWatcher<void> watcher;

    //Setting up connections
    //Progress dialog
    connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(progressValueChanged(int)), &progressDialog, SLOT(setValue(int)));
    connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(progressRangeChanged(int, int)), &progressDialog, SLOT(setRange(int,int)));
    connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(progressValueChanged(int)), ui->progressBar, SLOT(setValue(int)));
    connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(progressRangeChanged(int, int)), ui->progressBar, SLOT(setRange(int,int)));
    connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &progressDialog, SLOT(reset()));
    connect(&progressDialog, SIGNAL(canceled()), &watcher, SLOT(cancel()));

    connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(processStarted()));
    connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(processFinished()));

    //Gets the list filled
    for (int i = 0; i < ui->listTreeWidget->topLevelItemCount(); i++) {
        list.append(ui->listTreeWidget->topLevelItem(i));
    }

    //And start
    watcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::map(list, processRoutine));

    //Show the dialog
    progressDialog.exec();

}

extern void processRoutine(QTreeWidgetItem* item) {
    qDebug() << item->text(4);
}
```

I also added, in the UI (which holds all the previous widgets), a `QProgressBar` with the same SIGNALS/SLOTS. Keeping the code like the previous works as expected: the progress dialog shows up, and the progress bar updates exactly as the dialog.
Instead, if I comment the

```
//progressDialog.exec();
```

or I hide the dialog in some way, the process crashes (not always, sometimes it goes well). Looking at `qDebug() << item->text(4);` it crashes and the output shows randomly mixed text (they are supposed to be filenames). Also, the progressbar does not update itself when the `QProgressDialog` is not shown, even if the computation does not crash.

Note: I experienced a similar problem before in another function, and I solved it by setting

```
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(1);
```

on Windows only, OSX was ok.

So, what's the trick behind the `QProgressDialog` that makes all the things right? Is there a way I can use the `QProgressBar` instead of the `QProgressDialog`?

**NOTE**

This is the output when the process completes without troubles:

```
"C:/Users/Utente/Pictures/Originals/unsplash_52cee67a5c618_1.jpg"
"C:/Users/Utente/Pictures/Originals/photo-1428278953961-a8bc45e05f72.jpg"
"C:/Users/Utente/Pictures/Originals/photo-1429152937938-07b5f2828cdd.jpg"
"C:/Users/Utente/Pictures/Originals/photo-1429277158984-614d155e0017.jpg"
"C:/Users/Utente/Pictures/Originals/photo-1430598825529-927d770c194f.jpg"
"C:/Users/Utente/Pictures/Originals/photo-1433838552652-f9a46b332c40.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you comment `progressDialog.exec();` 
your `on_actionButton_triggered()` function finishes with destroying `progressDialog` so your signals are using pointers to nowhere.
Also `watcher` is being destroyed too before or after all mapping is performed, and afair it does not stop threads so they also working with nowhere.